# sql for finding first period in DateTime colums satysfying the condition

Tags: sql, linq

I have a table in DB where there are two colums - 'start' and 'end', which are in DateTime format.
What i need is a fast query that will return me first (counting from now) that row, in which 'end' is smaller by at least 1 hour (start[1] - end[0] > 1h) than 'start' in the row below (as I am ordering by 'start'). I was struggling it for ages and all i came up was empty returned list and it was very slow...

Comment: So, ordering the rows by start date, you're trying to find the earliest pair of rows, such that the end date on the earlier one is (**here I'm not clear**) compared to the start date on the later one. I'm not sure whether you want the gap to be smaller than 1 hour or greater than one hour. Of course, if you could add some *sample data* to your question, and *expected results*, it might be easier to work out, rather than trying to parse your narrative. Also, what RDBMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **DATEDIFF**, if you are using MYSQL.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE DATEDIFF(START_COL,END_COL)>1;
```

Refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html